# Combining Dot Below (U+0323), Greek in XeLaTex

Tags: tables, greek

I'm very new to LaTeX. I need to type dots below Greek characters for transliteration/transcriptional purposes.

I am using XeLaTeX because I have to do extensive typing in Greek.

Does anybody know a solution to this. I have spent hours looking on here, but the solutions I have found do not take account of the **tabular environment**. I'm typing the Greek in tabular. And I think this is causing the problem...(maybe?).

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}

\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Galatia SIL}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required]{Ezra SIL}



\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}cccccc}

  & ουεμ & καί μ(ετ)α & πρὸς    & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
  & γαβρ & ἀνδρὸς     & **\d{ἀ}**νδρὸς & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\

\end{tabular}
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem is that Galatia SIL does not have a combining under dot character.

You could use a different font like SBL BibLit or the Brill typeface.

Also the `xltxtra` package is causing an error and I don't think `xunicode` is needed either.

The `\d` macro command seems to work, but you could also just use `U+0323` (the Unicode combining under dot character) directly.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{SBL BibLit}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required]{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
\begin{greek}
\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}cccccc}
  & ουεμ & καί μ(ετ)α & πρὸς    & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
  & γαβρ & ἀνδρὸς     & **ἀ̣**νδρὸς & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
  & γαβρ & ἀνδρὸς     & **\d{ἀ}**νδρὸς & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
\end{tabular}
\end{greek}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the type of solution I was hoping to get. I had no idea the font was the issue. Thanks again.